# Multiple return values in Lua

Tags: lua

Ran into this problem earlier.
For a multi return value  function

```
fn=function() return 'a','b' end
```

the call

`print(fn())` returns `a b`

but the call

`print(fn() or nil)` returns only `a`

why? `or` should not matter since the first call was successful right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from [*Programming in Lua* §5.1 – Multiple Results](http://www.lua.org/pil/5.1.html)

> Lua always adjusts the number of results from a function to the circumstances of the call. When we call a function as a statement, Lua discards all results from the function. **When we use a call as an expression, Lua keeps only the first result.** We get all results only when the call is the last (or the only) expression in a list of expressions.

In the case of your example, the return value of `fn()` is used as an expression (the left operand of `or` operator), so only the first value is kept.